# camel loadbalancer failover custom error handler

Tags: java, apache-camel, load-balancing

With route defined in Spring DSL:

```
      <route>
         <from uri="direct:load1" />
         <loadBalance>
           <failover roundRobin="true" maximumFailoverAttempts="1"/>
            <to uri="broker1:queue:queue"/>
            <to uri="broker2:queue:queue"/>
        </loadBalance>
      </route>
```

How would implement a custom error handler or processor to handle the out body when the failover exhausted the maximumFailoverAttempts?

To make it simpler to understand, both broker1 and broker2 endpoints are unavailable, a processor should then be invoked to set the out body to "failed" as an example.

Currently I'm using `<doTry>`

```
       <route>
         <from uri="direct:load1" />
         <doTry>
         <loadBalance>
           <failover roundRobin="true" maximumFailoverAttempts="1"/>
            <to uri="broker1:queue:queue1"/>
            <to uri="broker1:queue:queue2"/>
        </loadBalance>
        <doCatch>
          <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
           <process ref="loadbalanceExceptionProcessor" />
        </doCatch>
      </doTry>
      </route>
```

Is there a better approach to this?